# Установка событий на html элементы

Tags: javascript, html, события

Есть функция, которая должна устанавливать события на html объекты:

```
function set(func, obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    document.getElementById(key).onclick = function () {
      func(obj[key]);
    }
  }
};
```

Пример ее использования:

```
set(go, {
 'g1': 'keepexit',
 'g2': 'keepbillow',
 'g3': 'keepstairs',
 'g4': 'keepjump',
 'g5': 'keepdrops',
 'g21': 'keephome',
 'g23': 'keepskin'
});
```

Почему все параметры функций в событиях на html элементах после выполнения этой функции - последний элемент объекта (`'keepskin'`)?

Comment: Обычная проблема с замыканиями в цикле: в момент вызова обработчика значение переменно `key` будет последним ключом из obj